# Extra mouse buttons not working in Ubuntu 18.04 VM guest, modified .vmx trick works on 16.04 guest but not 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, virtualization, vmware

So I'm running VMware Workstation Pro 14.1.3 on a Windows 10 x64 host. I've had an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS guest for a while, which at first didn't recognize the two side buttons of my Microsoft IntelliMouse Optical USB mouse. A quick search immediately yielded the most simple solution: adding these three lines to the VM .vmx file

```
mouse.vusb.enable = "TRUE"
mouse.vusb.useBasicMouse = "FALSE"
usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"
```

And that was the only **needed and sufficient** trick to perfectly do the job on VM restart.

However, since creating a new Ubuntu 18.04 VM, that same trick does absolutely nothing for me. I've verified by creating another fresh 16.04 guest that the trick does indeed work without any other manipulation, so it seems to be specific of 18.04.

Is there any reason why, did anyone else experienced this, and did you find a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on the web, tried it and it's working:
Stop your VM, add these lines to your VM *.vmx file:

```
usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"
mouse.vusb.enable = "TRUE"
mouse.vusb.useBasicMouse = "FALSE"
```

Start the VM and it worked for me!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Excellent first answer: **+1**

Comment: Is your VM an **18.04** guest? Because as stated in the OP it worked for me in an older 16.04 VM, **but not in the new 18.04 one**. And I've verified this by creating a fresh 16.04 VM: works. Fresh 18.04 VM: doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on VMWare workstation player

Comment: Sorry @Mickou06, I seem to have missed your answer from a while back...
I don't know what to tell you, it's still not working on mine... Could you paste the contents of your .vmx file ? Maybe there's another option in there that works, combined to those 3 lines, and that I don't have...